# Pointing a function to another

Tags: c#, function-pointers

Suppose I have two functions:

```
void DoesNothing(){}

void OnlyCalledOnce(){
    //lines of code
}
```

Is it possible to call `OnlyCalledOnce` and it actually run `DoesNothing` ? I imagine something like this:

```
void DoesNothing(){}

void OnlyCalledOnce(){
    //lines of code
    OnlyCalledOnce = DoesNothing;
}
```

and after that last line, whenever I called `OnlyCalledOnce` it would run `DoesNothing`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps you want a `delegate`?

Comment: `void OnlyCallOnce() { DoesNothing(); }` like this? - weird question this is probably the most basic thing in any programming language (calling a function/method)

Comment: Is your function called once per application execution? per PC? per installation?

Comment: I want the code inside `OnlyCalledOnce` to run only once, and after it runs, always I call `OnlyCalledOnce`, it executes `DoesNothing`. The endpoint is that I wanna call `OnlyCalledOnce` and run `DoesNothing`.

Comment: Oh, do you mean like the first execution will do something and then if you call the method again, it'll just skip the "first action" and call the other method?

Comment: Why do you want to call `DoesNothing()`? Is this an example or does it really do nothing? Why not just keep a boolean value that indicates if `OnlyCalledOnce()` has been called and check that before continuing?

Comment: I want to create something like a "null function pointer", so that I can let my functions run only once and after that, call something that doesn't do anything.

Comment: If it doesn't do anything, why call it in the first place? can you explain the real problem instead of posting dummy code?

Comment: I'll explain it even thinking that it doesn't need any further explanation. There are a lot of functions being called all the time, and for debug sake, I want these functions to run only once, so if it could do nothing after the first call, it would be great.

Comment: Your last comment makes more sense - you don't need it to call another method, you just only want it to execute one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use delegate?

```
class Program
{
    private static Action Call = OnlyCalledOnce;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Call();
        Call();
        Call();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void DoesNothing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoesNothing");
    }

    static void OnlyCalledOnce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnlyCalledOnce");
        Call = DoesNothing;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspected OP was looking for something like this, but the other answer is more reasonable since it uses a `bool` instead of `Action`. By the way, `DoesNothing` isn't needed here, either - it can be replaced by `() => {}`

Comment: Thank you for usefull addition, you are right. I just tried to provide the code by question's requirements and comments to your answer.

Comment: Of course. - It's not my answer, though. Those "edited" boxes can sometimes be misleading.

Comment: Happy to help .

Comment: I'm confused because in a comment to a different answer you said, *"Imagine that I have lots of functions that I want to run only once, I would have to have a bool for each, and this isn't feasible"*, but with this accepted answer, wouldn't you have to create an `Action` for each function? How is this better than the other? (I'm not criticizing this answer, just curious what makes it more acceptable).

Answer (score 5):

You can simply return early in `OnlyCalledOnce` like this: (assuming your `DoesNothing` example literally does nothing - it isn't needed)

```
bool initialized = false;

void OnlyCalledOnce()
{
    if (initialized) return;

    // firsttimecode
    initialized = true;
}
```

The `initialized` variable will be `true` after first run.

Comment: This works, but as I said in the comments, I want a "null function pointer", so that I can let my functions run only once and after that, call that null function.
Imagine that I have lots of functions that I want to run only once, I would have to have a bool for each, and this isn't feasible

Comment: You can share the boolean variable between all your functions.

Comment: @Daniel this is the most reasonable solution. you can also remove the `DoesNothing` method and just write `if (initialized) return;` in the beginning of the function. It's just 1 line.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could solve this is to maintain a list of strings that represent the methods that have been called. The strings don't even have to be the method name, they just need to be unique to each method.

Then you can have a helper method called `ShouldIRun` that takes in the function's unique string and checks to see if it exists in the list. If it does, then the method returns `false`, and if it doesn't, then the method adds the string to the list and returns `true`.

The nice thing here is that you don't have to maintain a bunch of state variables, you can use this with as many methods as you want, and the methods themselves don't need any complicated logic - they just ask the helper if they should run or not!

```
public class Program
{
    private static List<string> CalledMethods = new List<string>();

    static bool ShouldIRun(string methodName)
    {
        if (CalledMethods.Contains(methodName)) return false;
        CalledMethods.Add(methodName);
        return true;
    }

    // Now this method can use method above to return early (do nothing) if it's already ran
    static void OnlyCalledOnce()
    {
        if (!ShouldIRun("OnlyCalledOnce")) return;

        Console.WriteLine("You should only see this once.");
    }

    // Let's test it out
    private static void Main()
    {
        OnlyCalledOnce();
        OnlyCalledOnce();
        OnlyCalledOnce();

        GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you can use this:

```
private bool isExecuted = false;

void DoesNothing(){}

void OnlyCalledOnce(){
    if (!isExecuted)
    {   
        isExecuted = true;
        //lines of code
        DoesNothing();
    }
}
```

If you have multiple threads etc, you can do a lock(object) ..

Comment: What does `OnlyCalledOnce = DoesNothing()` mean?  Here it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score -1):

What's your problem with this?

```
void DoesNothing()
{
}

void OnlyCalledOnce()
{
    DoesNothing();
}
```

It will run DoesNothing() once you run OnlyCalledOnce()